# Why are listener lists Lists?

Tags: java, list, listener

Why are listener lists (e.g. in Java those that use `addXxxListener()` and `removeXxxListener()` to register and unregister listeners) called *lists*, and usually implemented as [Lists](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)? Wouldn't a [Set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) be a better fit, since in the case of listeners there's

- No matter in which order they get called (although there may well be such needs, but they're special cases; ordinary listener mechanisms make no such guarantees), and
- No need to register the same listener more than once (whether doing that should result in calling the same listener 1 times or N times, or be an error, is another question)

Is it just a matter of tradition? Sets are some kind of lists under the hood anyway. Are there performance differences? Is iterating through a `List` faster or slower than iterating through a `Set`? Does either take more or less memory? The differences are certainly almost negligible.

Comment: 'cause it's a list'ener? :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One important reason for listener lists to be lists (instead of sets) also explains why you often see them being iterated through backwards.  A common scenario involves a listener removing itself as a listener when it's notified of some change.  If the listeners were stored as a list and iterated forward (or stored as a set and iterated in some undetermined order), removing itself as a listener will cause a ConcurrentModificationException.

So, instead, the listeners are stored as a list and notified in backwards order.  Then, if a listener removes itself from the list of listeners when it is notified, it does not cause a ConcurrentModificationException or shift the indices of the other not-yet-notified listeners.

Comment: What if you don't care about the order?

Comment: If your listeners ever remove themselves in response to being notified, you should care.  Otherwise, you haven't lost anything by preserving the order.

Comment: if they remove themselves, why should I care ? I think that for most of the cases, it's ok to use a set. listeners shouldn't usually make assumptions about when they will be called compared to other listeners. Maybe a SkipList is the solution-in-the-middle for this? weird, I can't find a Java class for it.

Comment: If you are iterating through a set of listeners, notifying each one, and one of them removes himself from the set which you are currently iterating over, you *may* get a ConcurrentModificationException.  There are certainly other solutions to this problem, but storing the listeners in a list and notifying them in backwards order is certainly a simple one.

Comment: oh you mean removing the listener on the calling to one of its functions... yes, this could be problematic, but you could solve this in many ways (and yours assumes a lot about how it's implemented as there could also be multiple threads involved, plus it ruins the entire idea of order that you wanted so much), just as you've written. one way is to use a concurrent set. another is to have another set of listeners that are waiting to be deleted, that will be deleted after the calling to all of them have finished.

Comment: I don't understand how the iteration order (forward x backward) has any effect on the ConcurrentModificationException being thrown. Once you removed an element from the list, the exception is thrown on both subsequent calls to ListIterator.next() as well as ListIterator.previous().

Comment: Hmm... I don't think that used to be the case.  Has it changed?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of set? Should all listeners implement equals and hashCode so that a hash set is used, or would an identity hash set do? Is the use case of adding a listener to a list twice worth the complexity? Is there as simple a mechanism for making the set safe against adding or removing listeners during calls to their handlers?

There might be some performance differences, but there certainly are more complicated design, and it forces the multiple add-multiple remove decision into the library rather than leaving it to the application.

Comment: I think an identity hash set would be appropriate. But granted, there's no "CopyOnWriteIdentityHashSet" available out of the box, so using the common list idiom may be just simpler in achieving correct end result.

Comment: But: there indeed is a CopyOnWriteArraySet in Java 6, which is thread-safe ("Traversal via iterators is fast and cannot encounter interference from other threads."). According to http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes5.html "This implementation is well-suited to maintaining event-handler lists that must prevent duplicates."

Comment: @Joonas Since the Swing handlers are called in the Swing thread, the issue was always modifying the underlying collection and invalidating the iterator rather than concurrent updates. But if you did want those semantics, you certainly could use a copy-on-write set.

Comment: That's the cool thing with CopyOnWriteXXX: Modifying the underlying collection does *not* invalidate the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

You are totally right. Listeners should be added to sets. As you said, adding a listener more than once makes no sense. Furthermore one will not rely on the order of the listeners if you use sets. And thats the most important thing: One SHOULD NOT rely on it if you take software development serious and every single principle we found out to lead us to better design: Isolation, Independency, Responsibility.

Every aspect mentioned here (multi threading, performance, ...) has to subordinate itself in the first thought, but may be broken after if you have good reasons. And I mean VERY good reasons.

By the way: It's a bad practise to let the listener remove itself. Adding and removing should be symmetrical. So the listener should be removed through the object that registered it. If you have a lot of listeners involved you will get stuck soon.